# How to make Make AppBar background colour consistent with navigation bar color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having issues with changing `<AppBar>` background color. I'm using the `Container` component to set the maximum screen size.

This causes issues when the screen size is bigger than the maximum screen size. The `AppBar` background color is expected the rest is white.

How do I remove the white color and make it match the `<AppBar>` background color?

[image]

How do I get it so that white color to match the `<AppBar>` color so that the navigation looks consistent?

This is what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import {CssBaseline, Container} from '@material-ui/core/';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function ButtonAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I missing?

The navigation looks wired because it's surrounded by white.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in your css file and add:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: That changes the full background color of the body. I just want the header to be all blue but want the nav button to be where it is. I want the navbar to be consistent. And not white and blue as shown in the image above

Comment: I can help you, either give out more code (of its parent) or have a sandbox link posted here ?

Comment: I've updated the description with example code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `AppBar` outside the `div` with the class of `root` or remove the `width` from `root` class.

ADDED:

```
<div>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar style={{ maxWidth: 1280 }}>
      // ...
    </Toolbar> 
  </AppBar>
  <Container>
    // ...
  </Container>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not helped. Do you have an example

Comment: Now that you've added  the `Container` element, I would advice that the `AppBar` has to be outside of `Container` as well, because it has a maximum width property that is causing your problem. If you need an enclosing element, use `div`.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: If you want the `ToolBar` to be as wide as the `Container`, give it a class or style with the same maximum width.

Comment: I tried with no look. Have you got a working example

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/album